# Creating a len method in a new class - python

Tags: python, class, methods, string-length

I am developing a new class and to find the length won't work. Here is the code, and suggestions:

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.out_stack = []

    def enqueue(self, other='string'):
        self.queue.append(other)

    def __len__(self):
        len(self.queue)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return len(self.queue)` ?

Answer (score 5):

It should be `return len(self.queue)`, not just `len(self.queue)`.

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem

Answer (score 4):

You actually have to return the len-value:

```
def __len__(self):
   return len(self.queue)
```

Otherwise it will just be calculated and then nothing happens